# Why my logic for the below code doesn't work?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain me why my code doesn't work, where I am going wrong here?

I have written this code for counting the number 0-9 in an integer in java. If possible please help me with the best solution too.

Well I know it can be efficiently solved by using hash table but I'm looking for a solution which can be understandable by a newbie.

```
import java.util.*;

class CountNo {

    public static void main(String args[] ) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = a.next();
        char[] b = s.toCharArray();
        int S_len = s.length();
        int[] count = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        for(int i=0;i<S_len;i++)
        {  
           for(int j=0;j<=9;j++)
           {    
                if(b[i]==j)
                {      
                    count[j]+=1;
                    break;
                }
           }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" "+count[i]);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: please stop putting the text in bold. We understand from the normal text thickness what you are trying to ask

Comment: @sfat I don't...

Comment: Your entire problem description consists of *counting the number 0-9 in an integer*. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @shmosel, sorry, what I meant was: We can read the question with or without bold in the question description. sorry for the confusion

Comment: My mistake, I will take care of that in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because char `'0'` != `0`, it has code 48, so you need to change

`if(b[i]==j)`

into

`if(b[i]-'0'==j)`

or you could simplify logic, like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < S_len; i++)
    count[b[i] - '0'] += 1;
```

Comment: I have a doubt in this, as i understood that '0' in ASCII code is 48, but I didn't get that how it will change a char value which has values like "7" or "3" for instance, will change it to int value 7 or 3 after -(minus) it with "0" ?

Comment: @RakeshGowda because char and int are almost the same in java, so you can use either number 48 or char `'0'` (note single quotes!)

Comment: @IIya Bursov According to my understanding any number stored in char datatype can be converted to int datatype by just subtracting it from '0' or 48.  '7'-'0' = 7 how this works actually

Comment: @RakeshGowda not any number, only digits 0-9

Comment: so above 0-9 what should be the approch?

Comment: @RakeshGowda approach is to find good book about programming in general, java and algorithms

Comment: @IIya Bursov for instance if i want to compare char a=23; int b=23 if(a==b) then how should i do it? well i hope this if([a-'0']==b) will not work as you said it is limited to 0-9. i hope i am able to convey my doubt clearly

Comment: @RakeshGowda char with code `23` is equal to int `23`, so just write `if (a==b)` and it will be true, though string `"23"` is not equal to int `23`, you need to use `Integer.valueOf` to convert string to integer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map, in which the key is the digit and the value is the count.

You can learn more about maps here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html but essentially, a map is a Java object which relates a "key" to a "value", and does not allow duplicates. This is useful if you are trying to keep track of how many times a "key" (in this case, a digit) appears in a string or array.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if(b[i]==j)
            {      
                count[j]+=1;
                break;
            }
```

You compare char to int. Try this instead:

```
if(Character.getNumericValue(b[i]) == j){
count[j]+=1;
break;
}
```